# IBM Doors DXL: can't iterate over objects in module

Tags: object, module, iteration, ibm-doors

I have a rather peculiar problem with IBM Doors, using its DXL language:

I CAN get a variable to the module I want to access:

```
our_mod = module "<path_including_filename_of_module>"
```

I can NOT perform any of the usual functions pertaining to modules on that variable, e.g.:

```
name (our_mod) //or entering the string consisting of path + filename directly)
```

it gives me the error output: "incorrect arguments for fucntion (name)"

BUT, if I search through the folder containing the module, I can grab it via its filename:

```
Item x
Item my_module
for x in my_folder do
{
    if (name(x) == "<filename>")
    {
        my_module = x
    }
}
```

THEN I can perform `name(my_module)` or `type (my_module)`:
returns the filename and "Formal" as expected

But even if I get the module that way, I still can NOT iterate over the objects inside that module like with

```
Object o
for o in my_module do // ...in all my_module... does not work either, same error msg
{
    //Do what I came to do...
}
```

It just gives me the error message "incorrect arguments for (do)"

If anybody had any idea whatsoever as to what might be causing this, would be much obliged.

thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

There are several data types in DXL that have something to do with modules, all of them have different access functions (perms). E.g. variables of type Item are good for iterating over "everything in a folder or project". If you want to iterate over objects, you need a variable of type Module. As you already found out, the perm "module (string)" does NOT return data of type Module. It returns either a variable of type bool or of type ModName_ (which is a module *reference*, not a module), depending on the data type where you assign the result. For details, see e.g. the perms list on Tony Goodman's page at http://www.smartdxl.com/downloads/undoc31.html.

In DXL, make sure that you ALWAYS declare variables with a type, never use Auto-Declare if you want to keep your sanity (if you say `print our_mod` in your upper example you will find that you got a bool, which of course has neither a name nor a type).

For getting a variable of type Module, you first need to open the module (like in real life :) :)). You can open it using `edit`, `share` or `read`. E.g. like this

```
Module m = read ("/path/to/my_mod", false /* display */, true /* load standard view */)
if null m then error "could not open the module"
Object o
for o in entire m do {print o."Absolute Number" ""}
close m
```

Comment: Thank you for that elaborate answer. I will try that next opportunity.